# Show new files in green, deleted files in red

Tags: git, diff, text-coloring

I have an issue with the default `git diff` in that it shows file additions and deletions in white at the bottom of the diff, making it easy to miss them.

How can I set `git diff` to display file additions in green and deletions in red?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried different configurations? Have a look at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---colorltwhengt

I have `color=auto` by default btw